# Building a library targeting different versions of .NET

Tags: .net, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, nuget, .net-4.7.1

I have a library that I used to build against different versions of .NET by executing a command line like this: `msbuild x.csproj /p:TargetFrameworkVersion=v4.6.2 ...` multiple times with different value for the property TargetFrameworkVersion. Now I wanted to add .NET 4.7.1 to the script. The build for 4.7.1 succeeds but the next builds fail with a message like this:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\15.0\Microsoft.NuGet.targets(186,5): error : Your project is not referencing the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" framework. Add a reference to ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" in the "frameworks" section of your project.json, and then re-run NuGet restore. [x.csproj]

I searched for this message a lot but could not find any useful solutions that would fix my build script. The closest to a solution was [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/10334/your-project-is-not-referencing-the-netframeworkve.html%20this). But deleting project.assets.json before each msbuild did not help. Apparently there is a problem with restoring the NuGet packages for the different versions of .NET.
Can you please suggest a solution.

Comment: BTW, why do you need to build against different versions of .NET at all? In most cases, you should compile against a single .NET Framework version, and then other platforms (.NET Standard, Xamarin for example). There is no real value from what you do right now.

Comment: Have you tried manually deleting the bin & obj folders of that project not 
 just clean the build?

Comment: @Lex Li, because there are people on older .NETs (e.g. 4.5) that use the library, but I would like to move ahead and be current on it.

Comment: @Leo Liu, yes I did try it and the effect is the same as deleting just the project.json file: works on 4.7.1 and fails on earlier versions.

Comment: An assembly built against .NET Framework 4.5 can work flawlessly on later versions (unless you really would like to conditionally compile for some very special cases).

Answer (score 0):

OK, what I ended up doing is to manually add a line like this `<TargetFrameworkVersions>net452;net462;net471</TargetFrameworkVersions>`
 in the first PropertyGroup element of the project file. And then to **modify** (not to delete) the file project.assets.json by adding sections for the various targeted .NET versions. It is tedious work and I can imagine this becoming a pain in the tail for multiple projects with many versions. I saved a copy of the file somewhere in the project and added it to the repository, so that if it gets regenerated by VS - I can easily restore it.

If you can stick to one version only (the least common denominator) - you don't need any of it. [Here is my project.assets.json file](https://github.com/vmelamed/vm/blob/master/Aspects/Diagnostics/NuGet/project.assets.json) for a very simple structure and minimum number of dependencies project published on NuGet for .NET 4.5.2, 4.6.2 and 4.7.1. Let's hope that the VS team will find a better way for doing all this in the future.

Comment: If anyone can come-up with a better solution - I'll appreciate posting it here.